# how to improve publishing efficiency between ctps and client procs?

Tags: kdb

I have

host A - US

host B - germany

CTP is in host A and all client procs are in host B.

CTP is publishing data to about 30 client processes.

My question is :

If I move the ctp on the same host where the client processes are, will the data transfer speed improve ?

Answer (score 4):

1. If the 30x clients on hostB are subscribing to small tables only and/or filtering on sym to only receive subsets of tables then possibly data volumes could increase if the CTP is moved. As then all data will be sent rather than a subset.
2. If the 30x clients on hostB are subscribing to a table each without overlap then data transfer volume will not change.
3. If the 30x clients on hostB all subscribe to all data from the CTP then moving it to hostB would see a 30x reduction between the hosts. As then the data would only be sent once between the machines before fanning out to subscribers.

In most scenarios you will likely see a decrease. You can see what subscribers are listening to in `.u.w` in standard `tick.q`
https://code.kx.com/q/kb/publish-subscribe/
Then you can check counts of tables and sum up data that will be transferred to measure an estimate of how much traffic will increase/decrease.

Comment: Great answer. And in the optimal case 3, it's possible that `-25!` could help too: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/internal/#-25x-async-broadcast